# Make SASS-generated line comments start on the project root instead of the file system root

Tags: sass, compass-sass

For SASS-generated line comments, is there a way to denote the file location starting at the project root instead of the file system root?

Right now I have:

```
file:///Users/user-1/Sites/mysite/sass/_base.scss
```

And it would be awesome to have:

```
sass/_base.scss
```

So we don't run into conflicts/overrides like this one:

```
file:///Users/user-1/Sites/mysite/sass/_base.scss
file:///Users/user-2/Sites/mysite/sass/_base.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option that will let you make your sass-generated assets' line comments show the paths relative to the project root.

However, it seems to that you're asking for the wrong solution to your problem. The problem you're facing is that every time a different user compiles the assets, you end up with conflicts/overrides for the line comments. But you probably don't need to check in your precompiled assets to your version control system in the first place, and if that's the case, then you shouldn't do so, and should stick to precompiling them during deploys.

In fact, you should also compress your assets in production, which you can do by adding this line to your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```